# How to load a pandas column from a csv file with lists as lists and not as strings

Tags: python, pandas

when I write a list in pandas when I read it, its dtype is string and not array, is there any way to write a column of list in such a way that be again array type when we read it?

Here is what I mean:

```
d=[['d',['A','B','C']],['p',['F','G']]]

df=pd.DataFrame(d)

df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

when I run the following code,

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv')['1'].values[0]
```

the output is:

```
 "['A', 'B', 'C']"
```

but I want this:

```
  ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  Your example lacks sufficient information for me to follow the logic of what you are trying to do

Comment: i dont understand this part: pd.read_csv('file.csv')['1'].values[0]="['A', 'B', 'C']"
You open a csv as pandas dataframe, then get a column as numpy array and then try to save a string or list in it?

Comment: I have everything in the question. u only need to copy and pate my code and data to see. The output of the above code is string not array. it has `"` around the list but I want something that printed. a list without `"` .

Comment: @n4321d please see the edit

Comment: If you are in control of it, maybe consider changing your data format. Dataframe cells aren't supposed to hold sequential values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one solution would be to run it through [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

you make a dictionary with the column name as key and the converter function as value. and pass that into read_csv with the keyword converters

Note that if your column has mixed data (also strings and other stuff) you might want to write a custom function which filters and converts the different types

```
from ast import literal_eval
df1 = pd.read_csv('file.csv', converters={'1': literal_eval})
df1
```

output:
[image]

```
type(df1["1"][0])
```

output:

[image]